# Do I need an AAR file for an Axis web service?

Tags: java, web-services, axis

I am getting started with an Axis-based web service, written in Java, which will run on WebSphere.

My question is, can I just bundle this up as a web application like I usually do, as a WAR file inside of an EAR file, or do I need an AAR file, inside a WAR file, inside an EAR file?

Or are AAR files just for packaging up web service components on their own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you do need an .aar file if you are using Axis2.

Remember an .aar file is just a .jar file, with a particular structure:
A services.xml file in the META-INF folder.